# How to register a factory

Tags: unity-container

How do I convert the following to use RegisterFactory

```
container.RegisterType<Func<string, ICar>>(new InjectionFactory(
            ctx => new Func<string, ICar>(name => container.Resolve<ICar>(name))));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
container.RegisterFactory<Func<string, ICar>>((c, type, name) => c.Resolve<ICar>(name));
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  How would I inject the carFactory into a MyViewModel constructor?  When I use public MyViewModel(Func<string, ICar> carFactory){ } I get an "Resolution Failed Exception".  When I use the old RegisterType method in my earlier post it works correctly.

Comment: I had a similar problem i resolved it by adding the legacy extension to the container        ```(container as UnityContainer)?.AddNewExtension<Legacy>();```

Comment: I still get a "Resolution Failed Exception" using John C recommendaton